# Need PLSQL block to update Table A and also insert same values in Table B

Tags: sql, plsql, plsqldeveloper, insert-update

I need to write a PLSQL block that copies values from Column A for a certain record in Table A and updated the copied values in same Column A for another record in the same Table A. Also, these values are to be inserted in a log table Table B.

For Example:
Table **emp** has columns: emp_id, salary, shift

| EMP_ID | SALARY | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | A |
| 1 | 200 | B |
| 2 | 300 | A |
| 2 | 400 | B |

Table **emp1** has columns: emp_id, salary, shift and is empty.

In Table emp for EMP_ID=2 the SALARY should be same as EMP_ID=1 as per the SHIFT.
So the table should look like below:

| EMP_ID | SALARY | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | A |
| 1 | 200 | B |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 200 | B |

Along with this, we want the change to be logged in Table **emp1** after checking if such records do not already exist.
So the **emp1** table should look like below after the update:

| EMP_ID | SALARY | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 200 | B |

So far I have the below PLSQL block which is using a cursor to update the **emp** table correctly but the insert query is looping all the data from table **emp** and inserting duplicate values in table **emp1**.

```
Declare
  cursor c_emp is
    select e2.emp_id, e1.shift, e1.salary
      from emp e1, emp e2
     where e1.shift = e2.shift
       and e1.emp_id = 1
       and e2.emp_id = 2
       and e1.salary <> e2.salary;

Begin
  for r_emp in c_emp loop

    update emp 
    set salary = r_emp.salary 
    where shift = r_emp.shift;
 
    insert into emp1 (emp_id,salary,shift)
    (select 2,r_emp.salary,r_emp.shift
    from emp
    where not exists (select * from emp1
                  where emp1.emp_id = 2
                   and emp1.shift = r_emp.shift));

  end loop;                    
end;
```

This PLSQL block when run is updating table **emp** as expected but insertion in table **emp1** is duplicating like below which is wrong.

| EMP_ID | SALARY | SHIFT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 100 | A |
| 2 | 200 | B |
| 2 | 200 | B |
| 2 | 200 | B |
| 2 | 200 | B |

How do I edit this query?

Answer (score 0):

You got duplicates in the 2nd table because you're inserting rows for each loop round.

---

Which rules should be followed? Why is `emp_id = 2` supposed to be updated according to values of `emp_id = 1`, and not vice versa? What if there's also `emp_id = 3` in the source table?

Also, I'd expect `emp1` table to contain **old** values related to updated rows, not new values; what is its purpose? If it were as I presumed, `emp1` would be an *archive* table, showing how values looked before they were updated.

---

Anyway: as you put it, I'd suggest 2 `merge` statements instead of PL/SQL and loop. I presumed that the *lowest* `emp_id` value is *referential*, and values higher than that should be updated.

Initial state:

```
SQL> select * from t_emp;

    EMP_ID     SALARY SHIFT
---------- ---------- -----
         1        100 A
         1        200 B
         2        300 A
         2        400 B

SQL> select * from t_emp1;

no rows selected
```

Update 1st table:

```
SQL> merge into t_emp a
  2    using t_emp b
  3    on (a.emp_id > b.emp_id and
  4        a.shift = b.shift
  5       )
  6  when matched then update set
  7    a.salary = b.salary
  8  where a.emp_id > (select min(c.emp_id) from t_emp c);

2 rows merged.
```

Update/insert 2nd table:

```
SQL> merge into t_emp1 a
  2    using t_emp b
  3    on (a.emp_id = b.emp_id and
  4        a.shift = b.shift
  5       )
  6  when matched then update set
  7    a.salary = b.salary
  8  when not matched then insert (emp_id, salary, shift)
  9    values (b.emp_id, b.salary, b.shift)
 10  where b.emp_id > (select min(c.emp_id) from t_emp c);

2 rows merged.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from t_emp;

    EMP_ID     SALARY SHIFT
---------- ---------- -----
         1        100 A
         1        200 B
         2        100 A
         2        200 B

SQL> select * from t_emp1;

    EMP_ID     SALARY SHIFT
---------- ---------- -----
         2        100 A
         2        200 B

SQL>
```